# How do I use jest to mock a promisified function

Tags: node.js, mocking, jestjs

I have a very simple little utility function

`xml2JSON` as follows

```
import { promisify } from 'util'
import { parseString } from 'xml2js'

const xml2js = promisify(parseString)

const xmlToJSON = async xml => xml2js(xml)

export default xmlToJSON
```

I am trying to test it with jest, mocking out the stuff I don't need to care about

```
import * as util from 'util'
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js'

import xmlToJSON from './xmlToJSON'

jest.mock('util')
jest.mock('xml2js')

describe('xmlToJSON', () => {
  const promisifiedParseString = jest.fn()
  util.promisify = jest.fn(() => promisifiedParseString)
  const js = { some: 'result' }
  const xml = '<some>result</some>'
  let result

  beforeAll(async () => {
    promisifiedParseString.mockResolvedValue(js)
    result = await xmlToJSON(xml)
  })

  it('promisified the original parseString', () => {
    expect(util.promisify).toHaveBeenCalledWith(xml2js.parseString)
  })

  it('called the promisified parseString with the xml', () => {
    expect(promisifiedParseString).toHaveBeenCalledWith(xml)
  })

  it('returned the expected result', () => {
    expect(result).toEqual(js)
  })
})
```

But I am getting the error

```
TypeError: xml2js is not a function

  4 | const xml2js = promisify(parseString)
  5 | 
> 6 | const xmlToJSON = async xml => xml2js(xml)
    |                                ^
  7 | 
  8 | export default xmlToJSON
  9 |
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Based on suggestion below I have tried changing the order of the imports

```
import * as util from 'util'
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js'

jest.mock('util')
jest.mock('xml2js')
const promisifiedParseString = jest.fn()
util.promisify = jest.fn(() => promisifiedParseString)
import xmlToJSON from './xmlToJSON'

describe('xmlToJSON', () => {
  const js = { some: 'result' }
  const xml = '<some>result</some>'
  let result

  beforeAll(async () => {
    promisifiedParseString.mockResolvedValue(js)
    result = await xmlToJSON(xml)
  })

  it('promisified the original parseString', () => {
    expect(util.promisify).toHaveBeenCalledWith(xml2js.parseString)
  })

  it('called the promisified parseString with the xml', () => {
    expect(promisifiedParseString).toHaveBeenCalledWith(xml)
  })

  it('returned the expected result', () => {
    expect(result).toEqual(js)
  })
})
```

but it made no difference

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `util.promisify` behaviour before you import the file which is using it.

So the order should be something like:

```
util.promisify = jest.fn(() => promisifiedParseString)
import xmlToJSON from './xmlToJSON'
```

Comment: Alas that made no difference

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you need to also change

```
import xmlToJSON from './xmlToJSON'
```

to

```
const xmlToJSON = require('./xmlToJSON');
```

because imports get hoisted to the top of the script, and requires do not.